# AWS S3 Policy to Restrict User to List Only Certain Folders in a Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having difficulty creating an AWS S3 policy to allow a customer to list and access only certain objects with extensions in specific folders and subfolders, while not being able to list or access other folders, subfolders, or objects.

Let's say we have this structure:

```
S3
.
├── BucketManagement
|   └── Accounting
|
├── BucketHR
|   ├── Insurance
|   └── Resume
|
└── BucketCustomers
    ├── custAcmeAnvils
    ├── custBoboBakery
    |   ├── projCakewalk
    |   |   ├── batter.txt
    |   |   ├── cupcake.txt
    |   |   ├── PROFIT.XLS
    |   |   └── cooktime.txt
    |   ├── projPieFace
    |   └── projFlourPower
    |       ├── dough.txt
    |       └── LAWSUITS.DOC
    └── custCocoCabana
```

I've created an IAM user for my customer "Bobo's Bakery". I want to allow my customer Mr. Bobo to see and access only certain folders, subfolders, and objects (files). I don't want Mr. Bobo to see or access any other buckets, folders, subfolders, or objects.

In this example, I only want Mr. Bobo to be able to list and download the objects with the ".txt" extension in certain subfolders and not see, list, or access any other folders, subfolders, or objects with other extensions.

Ideally, when Mr. Bobo logs in to the S3 console, he sees ONLY this bucket (I know this may not be possible, as all buckets will have to be visible):

```
BucketCustomers
```

Then when Mr. Bobo clicks that bucket, he sees ONLY this folder "custBoboBakery":

```
BucketCustomers
└── custBoboBakery
```

Then when Mr. Bobo clicks that folder, he sees ONLY these 2 subfolders "projCakeWalk" and "projFlourPower":

```
custoBoboBakery
├── projCakeWalk
└── projFlourPower
```

Note: I do not want Mr. Bobo to see the subfolder projPieFace.
Then when Mr. Bobo clicks either subfolder projCakewalk or projFlourPower, he sees ONLY objects with the ".txt" extension.

```
projCakewalk
├── batter.txt
├── cupcake.txt
└── cooktime.txt

projFlourPower
└── dough.txt
```

Mr. Bobo should not be able to see the objects with ".XLS" or ".DOC" extensions. He can then download those .txt files. Mr. Bobo should not have delete or upload permissions.

Can you advise how to write this policy?

Answer (score 2):

S3 is a flat file system object storage. This means all the files and folders you access are eventually flat names.

For instance your folder path `projCakewalk->batter.txt` has the name `projCakewalk/batter.txt` for your file. This means if you want to access this specific file, you need to use the complete name(path).

To restrict access to specific folders and paths, S3 provides ability to create bucket policies as well as IAM policies - Structurally they both are similar. To serve your purpose, you could refer to this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

A sample policy from the page is put down below

```
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
     "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
   },
  {
     "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
     "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","home/", "home/David"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
     "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["home/David/*"]}}
   },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": ["s3:*"],
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company/home/David/*"]
   }
 ]
}
```

In the above policy, 
with the first part, you allow access to list all buckets(you do not need this)
with the second part, it allows access to list specific subfolders for my-company bucket
with the third part, it allow access to only specific file name pattern (you can use similar condition for restricting access to specific files - Just remove asterisk)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually used that link and the code as the basis for my IAM policy, but found that in that example from Amazon AWS, it would list the subfolders names of "Bob" and "Adele" under the "home" folder. In my example, I'm trying to prevent my user from even seeing those other subfolder names. I suspect there is an "Effect":"Deny" policy that I need to define which, I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Yup you are on the right track. You simply need to define the `"Effect":"Deny"` for the corresponding folders

Comment: @scottkeen - I'm trying to get this working now too, but the Deny's just don't seem to stick. Did you ever get the Deny working as suggested by The Cloud Guy